# Add new section in prestashop with friendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, prestashop

Im trying to add a new section that collect the name of a shop and show their information that are in the DB.

All of this I do and works fine, I created 1 directory with the name "Shop-info" and inside a file called "shop.php" that take the name with the GET method. for example: /Shop-info/shop.php?name=X.

But now Im trying to do this with friendly url's, I've tried add to the .htaccess file this rule:

RewriteRule ^Shop-info/(.*)$ [my-server]/Shop-info/shop.php?name=$1

but don't work, when I enter the URL: [my-server]/Shop-info/miami --> appear the 404 error of prestashop.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use R and NC flags and then check if page is redirecting to the          `/Shop-info/shop.php?name=$1` . NC flag will let your pattern case-insensitive to pass as, I can see some of alphabets are in capital letters in your pattern. R for test purpose only if its redirecting to the right page or not, once you hit the right page as you want, you omit this R flag so in the address bar you see seo friendly url.

I just noticed one another issue, if your htaccess file resides in root folder that means, after a successful redirection to `your-server/Shop-info/shop.php?name=$1` , it can hit back to the htaccess file again with the url and so there can be a loop as your pattern contains `Shop-info` which can satisfy redirected url so instead of `Shop-info` if your pattern is something like `^Shopinfo/(.*)$` then, it wouldn't repeat the process of redirection.

Comment: I tried your solution but i've the same error. It can be a problem with the configuration of prestashop in the .htacess file?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#Domain: my-domain
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/my-server/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]
RewriteRule ^my.server/shopinfo/(.*)$ /my-domain/my-server/shop.php?nombre=$1  [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: # Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>